# Django return not loading all dependencies

Tags: django

I created a login page in Django that has various Javascript and CSS dependencies, which I have placed in the same folder and provided proper script locations. When I test only the page in a browser it seems to load fine with all the files. However, when I send any request and when Django returns the web page using `return render(request, 'InsertPage/login.html')` only the web page is returned and not the dependent files.

Comment: The files are never send with that response. If the response contains an image for example, then the browser will make *extra* requests to download these images.

Comment: then what is the solution? for my page there are various js css images which needs to be loaded..here i can see only the static html file is returned and no external file. what can be done ?

Comment: you let the browser make extra requests to fetch these dependencies.

Comment: how can i manage that ?

Answer (score 0):

That is **normal behavior**.

Dependent files are *not* sent with the response. What happens is that the browser inspects the response, looks for links in the HTML (like images, scripts, stylesheets, etc.), and makes extra requests to fetch these dependencies as well. These dependencies can be located somewhere else (for example a different web server).

You can let Django serve [*static files*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/) in development mode, but it is strongly advised not to use that in production. Then you need to configure the Nginx/Apache/… server such that it serves these files.

Comment: how can i make it work in my case then ? the files are located in the same folder as the html page..

Comment: @VipuLShiNde: normally you do *not* locate static files in the templates directory: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/